# About the metric and embedding of sphere

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Let $S^2$ be the $2$-dimensional sphere with a metric $g$.

**Q**:

Can we or how to find a smooth  map $f:S^2\to \mathbb R^3$, such that

(1) $f$ is diffeomorphic to  its image $Im(g)=:M$,

(2) $M$ with the induced metric from $ds^2$ of $\mathbb R^3$,  is isometric to $(S^2,g)$, where $ds^2$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$, and the isometric is given by $f^{-1}:M\to S^2$.

I do not know any work about the problem(maybe solved).
Any reference about the problem is welcome

Answer (score 6):

If the Gauss curvature is positive, such an embedding is known to exist, a result of Nirenberg. But if there is a point of zero Gauss curvature, I think that nothing is known. See the book Qing Han, Jia-Xing Hong, **Isometric Embedding
of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces** for the best known results.

Comment: A little clarification: When the Gauss curvature is positive, then it's known as the Weyl problem and was proved independently. by Nirenberg and Pogorelov. For nonnegative Gauss curvature, there is a result by Guan and Li, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214454874. If the Gauss curvature is negative somewhere, then nothing is known.

Comment: Pogorelov showed the following more general result. For a general metric on $S^2$, if the Gaussian curvature is strictly greater than $-\kappa$ for a nonnegative number $\kappa$, then the metric can be isometrically embedded into the simply-connected complete space form of curvature $-\kappa$.